# Azure AD SSO Multi-Tenant App / AD FS Claims Provider Issue

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory, adfs2.0

Some background:

My company (acting as the SP) currently handles SSO with our federated partners (IdP's) through AD FS 2.0. Each partner is set up as a Claims Provider and rules for transforming incoming claims that will be sent to our web application are created.

After authentication the token containing the claims is posted to our STS endpoint (e.g. https://sts.companyname.ca/adfs/ls) where the claims are transformed and sent to our web application url (e.g. https://companyname.ca/externalsignin.aspx) and processed by OWIN middleware that precedes account lookup/creation.

This all works perfectly. Now we being tasked with integrating Azure AD SSO into the mix to help make the onboarding process easier.

I have gotten as far as creating a new directory in Azure and creating a new application within. I've marked the application as Multi-tenant and set the Reply url to "https://sts.companyname.ca/adfs/ls". In the AD FS 2.0 client on our server I created a new Claims Provider called "AzureAD" and imported the metadataurl from the endpoints section of the app on Azure console. Testing a log in with an email from our Tenant worked perfectly. The problem lies when testing with an organization email from another tenant, the authentication fails with a bad request message:

[image: Bad Request Image]

After some research it seems this was due to the login form being constructed for login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid whereas login.microsoftonline.com/common should be used for multi-tenant apps. So I re-imported the metadata from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml instead and updated. [image]

Now I can actually see a request for consent when I log in with another tenant organizational account, but after authentication the post to sts.companyname.ca/adfs/ls fails because the token was signed for "sts.windows.net/0000-000000-000000-0000" but the claims provider in AD FS is identified by sts.windows.net/{tenantid} placeholder.[image]

I have no idea how to make this work with only a single Azure claims provider with a templated end point (also I can only ever add 1 azure claims provider since they all use the same signing certificates).

Any help overcoming this hurdle would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this won't work because of a impedance mismatch on how Azure AD issues the token (same signing key but different tenant issuers) with the constraint in ADFS which does not allow multiple Claims Provider trusts with the same signing key.

The way to do this is one of the following

1. Use Azure AD B2B to invite the guests from one or more Azure AD tenants into your Azure AD tenant and then hook up ADFS to your tenant as one CP trust.
2. With ADFS 2016, we also had request to treat each Azure AD tenant as a distinct CP trust with different policy/rules on claims acceptance/augmentation. To this end, we now allow each Azure AD tenant to be modeled as unique CP trust.

Hope that answers your question.

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: Thank you. Azure AD B2B looks like it might be the way to go. It seems though that the process for inviting external users relies on importing a csv file with a 2000 line maximum. Does this require us to invite a new user every time they get added to the partners tenant for them to be able to access our resources? Our partners are school boards with some having 100,000+ users that would require access with new students being added all the time.

Comment: I ended up writing some additional code to use OpenIdConnectAuthentication with an additional provider instead of doing it through ADFS. Cheers!